# Azure Function with path parameter doesn't work on Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure, google-apps-script, azure-functions

I created a very simple .Net Core project which hosts functions.
I followed this steps to initial set it up: [C# functions setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=macos%2Cazure-cli#create-a-local-function-project).
All was working fine, locally and on Azure Function App service.

Then I wanted to have a /Get method and /Get/{id}, I set it up by doing:

```
 [Function("Get/{id}")]
 public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunByIdAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req, string id)...
```

everything was working fine locally, but on azure opening the Get/{id} function was showing this:
[image]

I tried to add a function.json with route key set to:

```
"route": "get/{id}"
```

but again all was fine locally but Azure was showing me the same error.

I created a /Delete function which supposed to get a parameter from the URL path but the same error show up (only on azure).
Any other functions, which not take a parameter from the path works fine.

Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by adding a route to the method signature:

```
[Function("GetById")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunByIdAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Get/{id}")] HttpRequestData req, string id)
```